# Why does not http response work with 3G in my android device?

Tags: android

I wrote some code in android and I am tryin to get http response from a website . I done it but when ı uploade the app to the my android device ,I can not read response while call is coming. Actually ,I wanna show the http response in the screen while call is coming. please help me Thanks.....

My HTTPPOST AND READ CODES

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 


    InputStream is = null;
     String result = "";
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

     try 
     {  HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
     params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.whois118.com/broadcast.php");
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefon",tlf));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", hash));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

           is = entity.getContent();
           int length;
      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
      }
  // convert response to string
      try 
      {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line = null;

       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();



       Log.v("log","Result :"+result);
  } 
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   Log.v("log", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }


    return result;
}
```

Comment: // concert jason codes

 String response=client.login5(incomingNumber,hash);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
   resusername = jObject.getString("name");
   a.setName(jObject.getString("name"));
    reshash = jObject.getString("hash");>



}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have adequate permission in your manifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I have alredy added permission .. Http response works but not with 3G.. It just works with wife connection..Is there a way to run with 3G?